# Cannot run program npm error when running Cordite network map JAR on Windows

Tags: corda, cordite

When running the network map using Java (as described here: https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service#using-java) on Windows, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (build-website)
>   on project network network-map-service: An Ant BuildException has
>   occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "npm": CreateProcess error-2, The system cannot find the file
>   specified around Ant part ...... @ 4:45 in
>   C:\Users\x.x\network-map-service\target\antrun\build-main.xml

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering this issue because the build file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="maven-antrun-" default="main" >
<target name="main">
    <exec failonerror="true" executable="npm">
        <arg value="install"/>
        <arg value="-g"/>
        <arg value="brunch"/>
    </exec>
    <exec failonerror="true" dir="website" executable="npm">
        <arg value="install"/>
    </exec>
    <exec failonerror="true" dir="website" executable="brunch">
        <arg value="build"/>
    </exec>
</target>
</project>
```

But Windows requires the executable names to be `npm.bat` and `brunch.bat` instead.

If you change the executable names in the build file, it will work correctly.